# Google Script Form with uploads, how to connect to spreadsheet

Tags: forms, upload, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Hi the below script has allowed me to upload files to Google drive however I can not seem to get the data entered in 'Name' and 'Date" to enter in to a spreadsheet.

Can anyone help me create or link a spreadsheet for the data to populate into.

Thanks

code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Operation Overview";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folder.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folders.createFile(blob);  
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by "+ form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully ";

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

form.html

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name.">
    <input type="text" name="myDate" placeholder="Date.">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

Comment: This is not directly related, but just to help to more fully understand the code.  You have the argument `e` in the `doGet(e)`.  Unless URL search string parameters are being passed into your app, you don't need to put that `e` in there.  It won't make any difference in how your code runs, but it's just nice to know what it's used for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **Spreadsheet Service**:

[Google Documentation - Apps Script Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

You can use Append Rows:

[Append Rows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#appendRow(Object))

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // Appends a new row with 2 columns to the bottom of the
 // spreadsheet containing the values in the array
 sheet.appendRow(["Jackson Jones", "jJones@email.com"]);
```

The above example uses the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` method.  You won't be using that.  You need a reference to the file.

You can open a spreadsheet file by id, or url.

[Google Documentation - Open a Spreadsheet by ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

```
// The code below opens a spreadsheet using its ID and logs the name for it.
 // Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
 // It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
 Logger.log(ss.getName());
```

Notice the `Logger.log()` statement.  To view the log, use the **View** menu in the Apps Script code editor.

It's critical to understand, that `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` returns a **CLASS**.  It returns the **SPREADSHEET CLASS**

[Google Documentation - Spreadsheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Once you get the Spreadsheet Class, then you can take the next step and use methods available to the Spreadsheet Class.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
Logger.log(ss.getName());
ss.appendRow(["Jackson Jones", "jJones@email.com"]);
```

In the above example, the data is hard coded, but you need variables instead of the constant values in double quotes.

So you need to get the data out of the form object, and into variables or a direct reference.

```
ss.appendRow([form.myName, "jJones@email.com"]);
```

I did check your code, and `form.myName` did return the name I entered into the name field.